# Unhide UINavigationBar LIKE in the Email App

Tags: iphone, email, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a View Controller where I perform a "search as you type". When I press on the SearchBar, hide the Navigation Bar, animated and I also show the scope buttons for my SearchBar. The problem is that when I press on a cell to push a new View Controller the Navigation Bar stays hidden. I KNOW I can set it unhidden, but it will animate from the top. I want to do something similar like in the Email app, when I press on a new cell, a new View Controller is pushed, and the Navigation Bar is animated from the right, like it belongs with the pushed View Controller. How can I make this happen?

Thank you.

Cosmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `UISearchDisplayController` to handle the search bar. The behavior you describe is the default behavior.

Comment: I understand, but I am fetching the search results from a web service, and I haven't found a good tutorial on how I can use a UISearchDisplayController to do this, and this is why I use a search bar and a table view, without any UISearchDisplayController.

Comment: Where you are fetching the results from is not of importance. You just go about your usual way, but implement the `UISearchDisplayDelegate` instead of `UISearchBarDelegate`. Keep in mind that the search display controller will put a new table view on top of your regular one, but you can just as well feed regular cells and answer the `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` to this table view as well, not discriminating. It will be transparent to the user.